# Undefined variable error in C macros (for customized prints)

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a custom printf that prints the file / line no , along with the error message , depending on the current print level set.  I've defined a macro for the same.  Given below is the code for the preprocessor:

```
#define DIE (s) \
    printf(s); \
    exit(0); \

#define my_print(level,s) \
if(level <= gPrintLevel) \
{ \
    char *buffer = (char *)malloc(strlen(s)-1); \
    if (NULL != buffer) \
    { \
       sprintf(buffer,s); \
       printf("[%s][%d]:%s\n",__FUNCTION__,__LINE__,buffer); \
       if (level == fatal) \
       {\
          DIE(s);\
       }\
    } \
} \
```

I'm calling the above pre-processor like this from inside a function:

```
myPrint(2,"Unexpected error encountered\n");
```

But, I'm getting the below compile  errors when I try to compile:

```
41: error: ‘s’ was not declared in this scope
```

Please help, what am I doing wrong ? Also, its appreciated if someone can tell me if there's a more elegant way of having customized print statements as above.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: That should be a `static inline` function instead.

Comment: And [don't cast the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)!

Comment: This doesn't appear to be your actual code (`myPrint != my_print`).  Please paste your actual code.  Also, which is line 41?

Comment: @H2CO3 How would `__FUNCTION__` and `__LINE__` be meaningful with a static inline method?

Comment: As an aside, you don't seem to be freeing your memory anywhere.  Also, why do you need this extra buffer at all?

Comment: @DanielFrey Function arguments to the rescue! `die(__FUNCTION__, __LINE__);`...

Comment: @H2CO3 The question is labeled C and C++, which presumably means that he needs a solution which works in both languages.  Which means casting the return value of `malloc`.

Comment: @JamesKanze Tagging a question with both C and C++ at the same time is wrong. No C code should be compiled as C++ and vice versa.

Comment: I don't know about the variable, but some notes -- first, the same items @OliCharlesworth mentioned. Second, your copy of the (unnecessary?) buffer lacks NULL termination... use `buffer = strdup(s);` instead (or better yet, don't even make a copy).

Comment: thanks for the super quick responses, that myPrint/my_print was a typo error, I couldn't copy/paste the actual code, as there's some issue from copy/pasting from my virtualbox linux terminal to the windows browser .  Anyway, I'm using malloc to avoid having a static char array to copy the contents using sprintf.

Comment: @H2CO3 You could implement both functions as static inline methods, but you still want a macro as you don't want to pass in `__FUNCTION__` and `__LINE__` in each call directly. Or just use KerrekSB's answer :)

Comment: @H2CO3 A lot of *code* from header files is compiled as C and C++ headers every day. Of course most of the content is just function prototypes but macros and static inline functions can be there as well.

Comment: @DanielFrey Actually, in real life, I'd go with a simple macro that expands `__FUNCTION__` and `__LINE__` in a **readable** way, and then passes those to a private handler function that does the real work (IIRC that's how e. g. `assert()` is implemented in most libc implementations).

Comment: @PavelŠimerda I'm not saying that "no C code **is** compiled as C++". I'm saying that "no C code **should be** compiled as C++". As to the header files: there's a common subset of C and C++, in which you write code, then it works in both languages (and it may even work correctly). `malloc()`, when used in the idiomatic (==right) way, is not included in this common subset.

Comment: @H2CO3 That is what I'm doing as well: Let the macro do the bare minimum that only a macro *can* do, move the rest to a proper implementation function.

Comment: @DanielFrey Yay, then we agree! :)

Comment: @H2CO3 I understood you, no clarifications needed. The malloc result typecasting is indeed redundant in C, but not incorrect, especially if your C code is meant to be compatible with C++ (i.e. if it is written in a subset of C and C++ using macros to distinguish the two when necessary). Technology and religion shouldn't be mixed together.

Comment: @H2CO3 That's nonsense.  There are plenty of cases where code must be compiled both as C++ and as C.  This code is clearly meant to be in a header, which could easily be common to both C and C++.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I would simply assume or mandate that the user provide a *literal* format string. In that case, you can concatenate strings:

```
#define MYPRINT(fmt, ...) \
  printf("Function: %s. Line: %d. " fmt "\n", \
         __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ## __VA_ARGS__);
```

Usage:

```
MYPRINT("The flargle %d has unexpected grobule %f", f->q, f->r);
```

This approach also lets you take advantage of the compiler's ability to analyze the format string statically and warn you about mismatching arguments.

(The code uses a GCC extension involving `##` to elide the final comma in case the argument list is empty.)

Comment: This sounds good, but I also want to have a level id to know if I should print this or not.  Can I use the abovementioned MYPRINT like this : MYPRINT(level,fmt,....) { if  (level > currentPrintLevel) printf(.....) } ?

Comment: @wildplasser: I believe I am stating that.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda: Then you should make an `DIE_LOCALLY` macro that passes the magic values through to your `gettext` or whatever string lookup, I suppose.

Comment: @wildplasser, i didn't get you, can u elaborate, what will not work ? tia !

Comment: It will not work if `fmt` is **not** a string literal (as @KerrekSB already stated in his answer) The caller _could_ construct the format string in a character buffer and pass a pointer to that buffer to the debug macro. (The good news: the compiler would not accept such a program. The bad news: debugging macros is hard. Debugging debugging macros is even harder)

Comment: @KerrekSB: Sounds like undue complexity.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda: Sure - but so does localizing fatal debug messages :-)

Answer (score 0):

OK thanks for all the help guys, the variadic macros solution works fine. This is the new defn of the macro now:

```
#define DIE(fmt) \
do { \
printf(fmt); \
exit(0); \
} while(0); \

#define my_print(x,fmt,...) \
if (x < gPrintLevel) \
{ \
    printf("[%s][%u]:" fmt "\n",__FUNCTION__,__LINE__,##__VA_ARGS__); \
    if (fatal == x) \
    {\
       DIE(fmt) \
    }\
} \
```

Comment: It looks like `DIE` shouldn't need to print the message again. `printf(fmt)` definitely looks like trouble (maybe `puts` would be better?). And you should wrap the `my_print` macro in a `do { ... } while (false)`, too.

Comment: @KerrekSB, you are right, removed the print from DIE, but why do we need do {....}while(false) ?